# Input values of variable always outputting as 0 in C++

Tags: c++

When I store user input in a variable and output it it gives a value of 0 for my `peoples()` function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int number1, number2, result;
// My result should like this
void addison()
{
    cout << "Enter first number:";
    cin  >> number1;
    cout << "Enter second number:";
    cin  >> number2;
    result = number1 + number2;
    cout << number1 << "+" << number2 << "= " << result << endl;
}

int name, age;
// This is the problem and always giving value of variable as 0 after inputting value.
void peoples()
{
    cout <<"Enter your name:";
    cin >> name;
    cout <<"Enter your age:";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Your name is: " << name << " Your age is: " << age << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int input;

    cout<<"People: 1 \n";
    cout<<"People: 2 \n";
    cout<<"People: 3 \n";
    cin>>input;

    switch (input){

        case 1:
            peoples();
            break;
        case 2:
            addison();
            break;
        case 3:
            cout<<"This is people 3";
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"You have entered Invalid Value";
            break;
    }

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

If anythings you don't understand just comment the matter.

Comment: Please post the code, the input, the expected output, and the observed output here.

Comment: My guess would be that you enter the `name` as `string` although it is defined as `int`

Comment: @ComputerLover You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the "name" variable into a string not an int.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int name, age;
> // This is the problem and always giving value of variable as 0 after inputting value.
> void peoples()
> {
>     cout <<"Enter your name:";
>     cin >> name;
> ```

Here's where the trouble starts. `name` is an `int`, which does not make sense. It should be an `std::string`.

When the user enters something which cannot be parsed as an integer number and you try to extract it into an `int`, `std::cin` is set to an **error state**. In addition, depending on which version of C++ you are using, the following happens:

- Before C++11, `name` is not modified at all.
- Since C++11, `name` is set to 0.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt:

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is
>   expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set. (until C++11)
>
> If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. *(...)* (since C++11)

Let's see what this means for the rest of your code:

> ```
>     cout <<"Enter your age:";
>     cin >> age;
> ```

Since `std::cin` is still in an error state, no input takes place. `age` is either not modified (before C++11) or set to 0 (since C++11).

> ```
>     cout << "Your name is: " << name << " Your age is: " << age << endl;
> ```

Before C++11, this would result in **undefined behaviour** because you never initialised `name` and `age`, and an attempt to print them without any previous assignment means that anything can happen. In practice, today, you'd "only" get seemingly random values printed, but in theory, your program could also crash or do all other kinds of strange things.

Since C++11, you have at least the guarantee that the `std::cin` extraction operators set the variables to 0, so there is no more undefined behaviour here. That's arguably better because you immediately notice that something is wrong.

---

In either case, the solution is **not to use `operator>>` directly** when you are dealing with human input. Human users are known to make mistakes when you give them a keyboard and ask them to type something.

Use the `std::getline` function instead. It reads a **whole line** of input into an `std::string` object. For `name`, this is already good enough if you did what I recommended previously and turned the variable into an `std::string`. It will even allow for names with spaces in them, like "Computer Lover".

For `age`, use the C++11 [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function to convert the input to an `int` and handle errors with wrong input accordingly, by catching exceptions which may be thrown.

Here is a simple example to get you started:

```
int name;
std::string age;

void peoples()
{
    std::cout <<"Enter your name:";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);

    std::cout <<"Enter your age:";
    std::string age_as_string;
    std::getline(std::cin, age_as_string);
    try
    {
        age = std::stoi(age_as_string);
        std::cout << "Your name is: " << name << " Your age is: " << age << "\n";
    }
    catch (std::exception const&)
    {
        // do something meaningful if the user entered
        // something bad, e.g. "xxx"
    }
}
```

---

When you get this to work, the next step would be to **abandon global variables**. They are quite the opposite of encapsulation and structured programming.

Comment: Just Thank you a lot for whole details about this codes !

Comment: @ComputerLover: You are welcome. The point (I think) is that C++ can be very easy to use if you just use all the convenience of things like `std:string` or `std::stoi`. When you have to deal with the complexities of stream error states or similar things, then this is often a sign that your code doesn't use the right tools.

Comment: Thank you again one more matter I want to told you and that is when I'm using name for taking input value on keyboard. On that time I can't using full name I mean If i just use a spaces beteween my values name then it's not working properly. So how can i deal with it ? I mean you answered it but i need to work the normal way is it possible ?

Comment: @ComputerLover: If by "normal" way you mean `operator>>`, then no, it's not possible because whitespace delimits input. (There *is* a way to change the definition of whitespace, but it's not something you want to know or do when you are new to the language, and even if you were not new, it would be more of a hack than anything else.)

Comment: For the `getline()` function errors is coming while I'm compiling this code : no matching function for call to 'getline(std::istream&, int&)'|

Comment: Then you are passing it an `int` and not an `std::string`. `std::getline` only works with `std::string`. If you want an `int`, you have to convert the `std::string` afterwards, as I have shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because you have defined `name` as an `int` when it should be a `string`. Change the definition of `name` and `age` like so:

```
string name; //This should be string
int age; //This could be a string too, if you want

void peoples()
{
    cout <<"Enter your name:";
    cin >> name;
    cout <<"Enter your age:";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Your name is: " << name << " Your age is: " << age << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions in which the code is provided through a link to another site. If that link gets broken, your answer will not make any sense at all.

Comment: Okay thank you for your suggestion but exactly I tried to add codes now as it but I couldn't did that.. there was coming a error messages always.